Quel est le sens de « lireriez » dans ce texte de Céline ?
Dans le livre Féerie pour une autre fois de Louis-Ferdinand Céline j'ai lu (c'est moi qui souligne) :

Vous verrez au cours des chapitres... si j'ai déjoué des stratagèmes ! si j'ai voyagé largement ! On a voyagé !... Lili et l'Ulysse... Sans incident un peu piquant je pourrais toujours vous tendre mon urne... pas drôle vous me lireriez jamais ! Ah mais m'achetez que clandestin !

Qu'est-ce que lireriez veut dire ? Je suppose qu'il s'agit du verbe lirerer ou lirerir, mais je n'ai pas trouvé ces verbes dans aucun dictionnaire.

Je pense que c'est une erreur intentionelle sur le verbe lire pour montrer que le personage n'est pas très fort en orthographe... c'est peut-être un conditionel, mais la forme correct serait liriez dans ce cas.

@Frank:  Mais, il n'y a pas de personnages dans cette œuvre: c'est Céline même qui exprime tout cela.

Ce n'est pas un livre qui parle ici? "Ah mais m'achetez que clandestin !" Est-ce qu'on achèterait Céline?

@PeterShor Funny that native French speakers all understand what lireriez is expected to mean but non native French speakers do not seem to be perplexed by mais m'achetez que clandestin which is less immediately intelligible to us.

@jiliagre: I did wonder about the que clandestin part, which I assumed was an idiom I didn't recognize. However, with vous verrez au cours des chapitres, vous me lireriez jamais, and m'achetez, it seemed clear to me that it was the book speaking. But I could easily be wrong.

@PeterShor Not wrong at all. Your comment was on the opposite absolutely to the point. (PS: my nickname is jlliagre, starting with JLLI)

Pour compléter la réponse de Kamala-1FTW, Céline utilise un registre volontiers familier et proche du langage parlé populaire dans des romans comme Voyage au bout de la nuit.
Ce pourrait aussi être le cas ici - la terminaison "-eriez" avec emphase sur le premier "e" est typique d'une langue relâchée, et parfois incorrectement appliquée comme dans "metteriez". "Lireriez" pousse cette faute plus loin, le redoublement du "r" paraissant encore plus incongru avec un effet comique certain.
